# Removing "Columns" and "Indexes" items from left menu in PhpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, config

Running MAMP on my local machine and trying to get PhpMyAdmin (4.1.4) set up to my liking. There are a few items in the left menu I want to get rid of - namely the "Columns" and "Indexes" sub-items under each table. They're extraneous to me - I'm not a DBA, just a wp developer, so I'd rather not just "get used to them". Most basic hosts doesn't have these options, and I'm hoping to make my local reflect that.

[image]

Tried googling for the answer for a couple hours now, but not surprisingly "phpmyadmin config remove left menu column" gets me a variety of results about removing columns from tables, and very little about the config options. Also dove into the config docs, and didn't find anything that looked pertinent. Anyone know how to get rid of the sub-items under tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't a means at this time to hide those specifically (unless you want to edit the source yourself). However, they don't automatically expand, so the easy workaround is for you to not click the plus sign `+` in front of the table name. You can click the text of the table name itself to select it, there's no need to expand the Columns and Indexes display for each table. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I got comfortable with a version that didn't have the + in the first place, and it's human nature to be a little irritated by usability changes like this. Guess I'll have to adapt.